# Create query who add two values when condition is true or get only one value

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two tables, first one

```
Table1 
ID   Name  Value    start       end         fk_table
1    edd   3     2013-03-25  2013-05-25       1 
2    tom   3     2013-03-25  2013-05-25       1
3    emi   3     2013-11-25  2013-25-25       1
```

And second table

```
Table2
ID VALUE
1   3
```

I want to add Value from **table1** and **table2** only when start <= Date AND t.end >= Date
But If the date is out of range I want get only value from **table1**

To assume that we have today date 2013-04-16, The expect result is

```
edd 6
tom 6
emi 3
```

I use doctrine and Symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution may depend upon your database engine, because different engines provide different SQL extensions. You would use

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Value+IF(Table1.start<=? and Table1.end>=?,Table2.VALUE,0) 
FROM Table1 
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.fk_table=Table2.ID
```

for mysql.

You have not written enough about your entities to provide you with Doctrine-specific code, but you might be able to run this with

````
$entityManager->createQuery($sql)->execute(array($dateParam,$dateParam))```.
````

Comment: thank you ;) , I have to  change to this "CASE" WhenClause {WhenClause}* "ELSE" ScalarExpression "END"  and it's working